# Dynamically sent variables in a mail (PHP)

Tags: php

I have plus icon next to an input field in my form to so I can add more input fields. Name of the fields are automatically generated to in this form -> "one_f1", "one_f2" ...

When I create the mail to send it out, I need to create a while loop for this so I can put all the values that are sent from the form. I am stuck while trying to add while loop in a variable called body because it has to be in the body of a mail.

how can I fix this?

Here is the code;

```
$body ='
            <ul>
                while(isset($_POST["one_f".$i]))){
                     echo "<li style=\"list-style: circle;\">".$_POST["one_f".$i]".</li>"; 
                }
            </ul>
       ';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with appending?

```
$body = "<ul style=\"list-type-type:circle\">";
$i = 1; // whatever number the first field is
while(isset($_POST['one_f'.$i])) {
    $body .= "<li>".$_POST['one_f'.$i]."</li>";
    $i++; // you forgot this in your code!
}
$body .= "</ul>";
```